# $\pi_1(B,x_0)$, $B$ a covering map of $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Take a covering map $p:B\to S^1$ of the circle, and $x_0\in B$.

> I want to prove that $\pi_1(B,x_0)\cong 0$ or $\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Clearly we have to consider the homomorphism

$$p_*:\pi_1(B,x_0)\to\pi_1(S^1,s_0)$$

I already know that $\pi_1(S^1,s_0)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, and that $p_*$ is a monomorphism (Munkres theorem 54.6 (a)).

Putting this together proves (unless I have misunderstood something) that $\pi_1(B,x_0)$ is a subgrupo of $\mathbb{Z}$.

<s>But I don't know how to rule out that $\pi_1(B,x_0)\cong n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\neq 0$.</s>

Thanks for any help. I'm open to any hint or alternative proof.

**Edit**. As C. Cain comments, $n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore the question is, is the rest of the argument correct?

Comment: As abelian groups, $n\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By knowing that $\pi_1(B,x_0)$ "is a subgroup" of $\mathbb{Z}$, you know that it is necessarily isomorphic to $\{0\}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ (since the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are the trivial subgroup or $n\mathbb{Z}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, as you correctly put).  Your argument is fine.

It looks like you want(ed) to prove that  under the conditions of the problem such a $p_*$ is necessarily an isomorphism. This isn't true, as you can take $p: S^1 \to S^1$ given by $p(z)=z^2$, and you will notice that the image of $p_*$ is the subgroup generated by $2g$, where $g \in \pi_1(S^1,*)$ is a generator (in other words, the image is $2\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$).